# Stuck on this who vs. whom scenario!

Tags: whom

Microsoft Word wants to change this "whom" to "who" -- but wouldn't that be wrong!?

*She previously saw another physician in the practice whom she describes as a “terrible doctor.”*

Comment: It seems right as it is to me. MS Word is really dumb sometimes...

Comment: @millman97: MS Word is simply reflecting the fact that native speakers are increasingly discarding ***whom*** in favour of ***who*** in such contexts. There might still be a few die-hards (such as yourself! :) defending the "accusative/dative" form, but all the evidence suggests they're fighting a rear-guard action on this one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, that's not true. It's reflecting the fact that it doesn't do an actual parse of your grammar.

Comment: @tchrist♦: I've no idea whether or to what extent Word "parses" text - I'd be quite prepared to believe it suggests the change purely on the basis of [how the ***whom/who*** ratio has changed over centuries.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whom%2Fwho&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28whom%20/%20who%29%3B%2Cc0) Whatever - if OP and millman97 want to say ***who*** is "wrong" in the cited context, they're entitled to their opinion, but the tide of linguistic history is definitely moving against them.